# Is there a way to restart or reset the python interpreter within a python doctest?

Tags: python, terminal, doctest

I am writing a short tutorial, and would like to be able to run the examples therein using python's doctest using

```
python -m doctest foo.txt
```

There is a point in the tutorial at which I want to start using a new, clean python interpreter. Is there a mechanism for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code module to create a new interpreter. You can even copy global/local variables.

There is a nice example within the Blender documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#insert-a-python-interpreter-into-your-script)

#### They advise the following:

In the middle of a script you may want to inspect variables, run functions and inspect the flow.

```py
import code
code.interact(local=locals())
```

If you want to access both global and local variables run this:

```py
import code
namespace = globals().copy()
namespace.update(locals())
code.interact(local=namespace)
```

The next example is an equivalent single line version of the script above which is easier to paste into your code:

```py
__import__('code').interact(local=dict(globals(), **locals()))
```

code.interact can be added at any line in the script and will pause the script to launch an interactive interpreter in the terminal, when you’re done you can quit the interpreter and the script will continue execution.

Comment: This still does not work within a doctest, because of how doctest interprets the >>> prompt. I suppose one could make an instance of InteractiveConsole, push commands to it to set sys.PS1 to something else, then start interacting with it. Maybe I'll try that if it comes up again.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is to start a new python interpreter inside the python interpreter you can just issue the command: os.system('python')

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> import os
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'os']
>>> os.system('python')
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> quit()
0
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'os']
>>>
```

if however, you want to restart or reset python interpreter and not start a new python interpreter like above you could look at this solution. I haven't explored it but should help you get started of.

[Restarting a Python Interpreter Quietly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431432/restarting-a-python-interpreter-quietly)

Comment: Clever, but it doesn't work from within doctest: when the child starts, it waits for input from stdin. I need to explore how doctest handles stdin and stdout to see if a related solution with popen might work...

Comment: The referenced "Restarting a Python Interpreter Quietly" appreach using the savestate recipe doesn't really reset the state, for example it doesn't undefine any interactively defined functions.

Answer (score -3):

To execute a file in IDLE, simply press the F5 key on your keyboard. You can also select Run → Run Module from the menu bar. Either option will restart the Python interpreter and then run the code that you've written with a fresh interpreter.

Comment: This answer is specific to the IDE you are using, it may no answer the question.